# is google correct translate for me?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

i have translated these 5 sentences with help of google translator is these are correct?

```
Hello from XYZ! {0} Your verification code is {1}                       = 你好从XYZ！ {0}您的验证码是 {1}。
This link of your XYZ Account, click on this link to confirm your email = 这 链接 您 XYZ 帐户, 点击 上 这 链接 至 确认 您的电子邮件.
Your new password is {0}                                                = 您的新密码是{0}
confirm your email                                                      = 确认您的电子邮件
No Reply                                                                = 无回复
```

Comment: No reply => Don't reply?

Comment: I believe I've seen in Microsoft's software translation guide which says you should always prefer “你” to “您”. At least you should use one single form among all places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 来自XYZ的问候！ {0}您的验证码是 {1}。
2. 这是您的 XYZ 账户链接, 点击此链接确认您的邮箱。

No problem remaining

Comment: "确认您的邮箱" might be better for the accordance.

Comment: @songyuanyao in place of what?

Answer (score 0):

= 你好从XYZ!

the above translation is too wired....
the right translation is "来自XYZ的问候！"